# Vertical scrollbar on multiple grids

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've three Windows Datagrids placed one below another on my XAML screen.Each of these grids have different column and rows(6 rows,5 rows and 4 rows respectively). I need to be able to show these grid contents in such a way so that no vertical scrollbar appears on any of these three grids.

If I don't put ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" on the first grid,row number 6 becomes outside of the visibility area.

What am I missing here please?

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="False">
        <Grid>


 <DataGrid Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="true"   
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,7,0,20" ColumnWidth="*"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">


 <DataGrid Name="Grid2" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="true" 
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,5,0,22" 
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">



<DataGrid Name="Grid3" Grid.Row="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="true" 
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Margin="0,5,0,22" 
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"       
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem if `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` is solving your problem ?

Comment: The aim is to show the grid contents without user needing to use the vertical scrollbar.Thanks.

Comment: What about making the grid and window bigger ?

Comment: And turn the monitor on it's side? ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Set each `DataGrid` `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` and `Height="Auto"` and the `ScrollViewer` `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` this will put only 1 ScrollBar for all DataGrid's.

If you don't want any ScrollBar at all you can use a `ViewBox` which will make everything smaller to fit on the page

Comment: Thanks!I tried this but no luck..I don't see vertical scrollbar on the first grid, but its' last row is not fully visible.

Comment: I see your ScrollViewer closing tag is inside of the the grid

Comment: Try to set each DataGrid's `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`

Comment: You must set the height of all RowDefenition's to Auto